# React js cannot change page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react js and have a simple webpage with a few different views, and then a few different pages. I can change between the views just fine, but when I try to go to a page (in this case the login page, but the other have the same issue) the url path changes and the default landing page is viewed instead. The default page when loading the website is: `http://localhost:3000/#/dashboard`

If I press the login button, the code is:

```
            <CButton
              onClick={async () => {
                window.location.href = "/login";
              }}
            >
              <CIcon icon={cilUser} className="me-2" />
              Login
            </CButton>
```

Then it should redirect me to the /login page, but instead I get redirected to: `http://localhost:3000/login#/dashboard`

Why is this?

This is my App.js

```
import React, { Component, Suspense, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./scss/style.scss";

import { UserContext } from "./UserContext";
import { getProtectedAsset } from "./getProtectedAsset";


const loading = (
  <div className="pt-3 text-center">
    <div className="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
  </div>
);

// Containers
const DefaultLayout = React.lazy(() => import("./layout/DefaultLayout"));

// Pages
const Login = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/login/Login"));

const Page404 = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/page404/Page404"));
const Page500 = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/page500/Page500"));

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    userID: -1,
  });
  const value = useMemo(() => ({ user, setUser }), [user, setUser]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
      <HashRouter>
        <React.Suspense fallback={loading}>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/login"
              name="Login"
              render={(props) => <Login {...props} />}
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/register"
              name="Register Page"
              render={(props) => <Register {...props} />}
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/register_club"
              name="Register Club Page"
              render={(props) => <Register_club {...props} />}
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/404"
              name="Page 404"
              render={(props) => <Page404 {...props} />}
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/500"
              name="Page 500"
              render={(props) => <Page500 {...props} />}
            />
            <Route
              path="/"
              name="Home"
              render={(props) => <DefaultLayout {...props} />}
            />
          </Switch>
        </React.Suspense>
      </HashRouter>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the HashRouter so the URL you need to aim for is `/#/login` not `/login`, but that isn't the biggest problem here.

By using `window.location.href` you are bypassing the Router entirely and making the browser load the application again from scratch from a new URL.

Assuming you are using React Router version 6 (the current version), the equivalent of `window.location.href` is [the `navigate` function from the `useLocation` hook](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#navigating-programmatically).

However, since you are just creating something to click on that navigates, you should be simply using [a `<Link>` component](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#add-some-links).

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

<Link to="/login">
    <CIcon icon={cilUser} className="me-2" />
    Login
</Link>
```

Comment: I see, thank you! It got me to the login page, but now I have another issue. On the login page, if I press some button, the page refresh and gets me to ´http://localhost:3000/?#/login´ (note the ?). If I press the button again it does not refresh. Why does this "?" prevent refresh on button press?

Comment: On the login page, when I login the server response is undefined if the url does not contain ?, the second button press works as it should when there is a ?. I also get the error "Error: Request aborted" if there is no ? in the url. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Pressing the button again has no effect because you are already at the URL it points to. The precise value of the URL is beside the point.

Comment: I don't know how, exactly, the server you are using works. I don't even know what server you are using.

Comment: Okay, well this solved my first issue, and I guess I am asking something different now, so I will call my issue solved and read some more and try to figure out what is going on with that ?, thank you for your help

Comment: If anyone else is reading my comments and have the same issue, adding "event.preventDefault();" to my handleSubmit function in the login page solved the issue with "?"